# Does Safari on OSX not support the "webkitdirectory" attribute for uploading folders?

Tags: html, macos, safari, webkit

I can't find a definitive repsonse to this question anywhere. It's a webkit feature so I assumed Safari would support it but it seems that's not the case according to my own testing. I've tried to simply add the

```
<input type="file" name="file_input[]" id="file_input" multiple="" webkitdirectory="">
```

but I don't seem to be having success. The drag and drop doesn't recognise the folder contents either, just the folder with no extension. At this point I'm pretty sure it doesn't work but I'd just like some confirmation since I can't seem to find any.

Comment: Same here... Did you find anything more on this issue since then by any chance?

Comment: Sadly no. Haven't tested on the latest version and 10.10 though so that might have changed. For the earlier versions the answer seems to be no.